# I cant properly pass variables between two views in Objective-C

Tags: ios, segue

I have two view controllers: `CropImageViewController` and `ImageCropperViewController`

In `CropImageViewController` I have this method:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue called");
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goBack"])
    {
        NSLog(@"processedText = %@",self.processedText);
        [segue.destinationViewController setProcessedText:self.processedText];
    }
}
```

Then, in `ImageCropperViewController`, I have this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"view will appear called");
    //self.processedImageLabel.text = self.processedText;
    NSLog(@"processedText = %@",self.processedText);
    NSLog(@"testLabel: %@",self.testField.text);

}
```

This is the console output. For some reason, "processedText" is always `NULL` no matter what.

```
2014-05-23 16:51:43.488 ImageCropper[9294:60b] prepareForSegue called
2014-05-23 16:51:43.490 ImageCropper[9294:60b] processedText =  E33
===..., ____ 

2014-05-23 16:51:43.493 ImageCropper[9294:60b] view will appear called
2014-05-23 16:51:43.494 ImageCropper[9294:60b] processedText = (null)
```

Comment: Instead of logging `NSLog(@"processedText = %@",self.processedText)`, try logging `NSLog(@"%@: processedText = %@",self,self.processedText)` so that you know you're testing the right classes.

Comment: Also log `segue.destinationController`. Cover all your bases. Make no assumptions!

Comment: In prepareForSegue, log segue.destinationViewController, and in viewWillAppear log self, and see if they give you the same address. Also, how are you declaring processedText?

Comment: Is `processedText` declared in the header files of both View Controllers? Or in both implementation files?

Answer (score 0):

I see your segue "***goBack***". Are you come back after pushed `CropImageViewController` from `ImageCropperViewController`?

So in this case you shouldn't use a segue. You should write an `IBAction` for your button (or i don't know what you have to come back) and when you press it do:

```
[self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but before this, you should call the `delegate` to pass the new value:

```
[_delegate changeProcessedText:self.processedText];
```

Obviously i assume that you know how implement a `delegation pattern`.

Another way could be use `KVO`, so observing from the **first** `viewController`, the `processedText.text` value in the **second** `viewController`.